# Strange Mongoose schema.js error - `options` may not be used as a schema pathname

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my schema, if I have `options` in `metrics : [ { options : {} } ]`then I get:

```
/home/one/cloudimageshare-monitoring/project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:282
    throw new Error("`" + path + "` may not be used as a schema pathname");
          ^
Error: `options` may not be used as a schema pathname
```

But if change `options` to any other word... like `qoptions`....then the error goes away. Why is this happening?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var FilesystemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    timeStamp : { type : Date, index: true },
    avaiable : Boolean,
    status : String,
    metrics : [
        { options : {
                data : String,
                type : String,
                unit : String
               }
        },
        { freeFiles : {
              data : Number,
              type : String,
              unit : String
             }
        },
        { total : {
              data : Number,
              type : String,
              unit : String
             }
        },
        { avail : {
              data : Number,
              type : String,
              unit : String
             }
        },
        { free : {
              data : Number,
              type : String,
              unit : String
             }
        },
        { files : {
              data : Number,
              type : String,
              unit : String
             }
        },
        { used : {
              data : Number,
              type : String,
              unit : String
             }
        }
 ]   
});

module.exports = FilesystemSchema;
```

Comment: Another problem here is that `type` is also a reserved word. Since you want to use it in your model, you have to write `{unit: String, type: { type: String }, ... }`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Mongoose has a number of `Reserved` schema names that can't be used, to avoid conflicting with Mongoose's internal implementation. The list, from the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema.reserved) gives the following as reserved:

```
on, emit, _events, db, get, set, init, isNew, errors, schema, options, modelName, collection, _pres, _posts, toObject
```

These terms should be avoided in your schema!

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the same issue, and since we can not use field names as common as `options`, `errors`... **I have disabled it like so**:

```js
new mongoose.Schema({ firstName: String }, { supressReservedKeysWarning: true })
```

Then, everything was working as expected.

Here is an issue in the mongoose repo on the subject [Remove all reserved keywords from schema](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9010)